# Flair HTML not working?

Tags: support, flair

So I want to include my combined Stack Overflow User Flair.  But the code provided, even on the [SO website](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair) generates the following:

[image]

so... what is going on? Is it related to my browser (Safari version 10)?
Good question. I tried with chrome as well:

[image]

Thoughts?

Comment: Works on my machine™.  They changed it recently, force a [browser page refresh](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12049/how-to-clear-the-cache-or-do-a-hard-refresh-in-safari).

Comment: You don't have a network profile, only a Stack Overflow account, that could be the reason.

Comment: @Stijn I have a combined network profile

Comment: Oh, it's not visible on your profile for me. I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjfqP.png) on your profile, and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GY1XL.png) on someone else's profile.

Comment: @Stijn when I click those links I get nothing :P haha, but I promise I have one. I am mainly on Mathematica SE

Comment: Ah, found it. http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/3651943.png loads for me, although your avatar is only partially rendered.

Comment: @Stijn except I can't load that page oddly...